# asp.net how to use sever side changes after post back

Tags: asp.net

In my asp.net application I have a some client side scripting that alters the page events and do different things. One problem I am having is when I post back to the server after all of the validation is done on the client side, I have a couple more validation checks on the server side (c#), and I want to show the proper error, but the page refreshes. I just would like to do some server side coding and if i need to go back to the page, go there as lasted viewed, with the error in the label, and changes i made on server side. Thanks for any help.

Comment: So you want to preserve client side changes _and_ server side changes after postback? Show example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must post it in ajaxy fashion.

I mean use ajax to post..
Evaluate the results on client side using JS.
Then if everything is fine do a redirect.
if errors exist you are still on that and can modify the html .

Answer (score 0):

Do your server side validations in an AJAX call instead of a normal page post back. Because, you are making a background server call, your page does not refresh and on validation failure, you can retain the browser side UI. If validation is successful then you can do your regular post-back for actual processing.

From implementation perspective, you can use Page Methods (or JSON WCF services) in ASP.NET AJAX for the same: see this tutorial to get started with Page Methods: http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx